# why do we need to set bean **binder.setBean(object)** in binding in vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow

This is the binding of all form fields. I am having long type of textfield so it cannot be null.

```
consumerBinder.forField(legal_hold)
    .bind(Consumer::getLegal_hold, Consumer::setLegal_hold);

consumerBinder.forField(deceased_fg)
    .bind(Consumer::getDeceased_fg, Consumer::setDeceased_fg);

consumerBinder.forField(household_id)
    .withConverter(new StringToLongConverter("Must be a number"))
    .bind(Consumer::getHousehold_id,Consumer::setHousehold_id);

consumerBinder.forField(ins_efid)
    .withConverter(new StringToLongConverter("Must be a number"))
    .bind(Consumer::getIns_efid,Consumer::setIns_efid);

consumerBinder.forField(ins_pqid)
    .withConverter(new StringToLongConverter("Must be a number"))
    .bind(Consumer::getIns_pqid,Consumer::setIns_pqid);

consumerBinder.forField(ins_rid)
    .withConverter(new StringToLongConverter("Must be a number"))
    .bind(Consumer::getIns_rid,Consumer::setIns_rid);

consumerBinder.forField(upd_efid)
    .withConverter(new StringToLongConverter("Must be a number"))
    .bind(Consumer::getUpd_efid,Consumer::setUpd_efid);

consumerBinder.forField(upd_pqid)
    .withConverter(new StringToLongConverter("Must be a number"))
    .bind(Consumer::getUpd_pqid,Consumer::setUpd_pqid);

consumerBinder.forField(upd_rid)
    .withConverter(new StringToLongConverter("Must be a number"))
    .bind(Consumer::getUpd_rid,Consumer::setUpd_rid);

consumerBinder.forField(upd_tmstmp)
    .withConverter(new StringTimestampConvertor())
    .bind(Consumer::getUpd_tmstmp, Consumer::setUpd_tmstmp);

consumerBinder.forField(ins_tmstmp)
    .withConverter(new StringTimestampConvertor())
    .bind(Consumer::getIns_tmstmp, Consumer::setIns_tmstmp);

consumerBinder.forField(deceased_dt)
    .withConverter(new StringTimestampConvertor())
    .bind(Consumer::getDeceased_dt, Consumer::setDeceased_dt);

binder.setBean(new Consumer());
```

Because of this i am getting default value 0 for long fields. But i want the form to be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can come up with two different options for you depending on exactly how you want the application to behave.

If you want to *always* show `0` as empty in the text fields, then you can create a custom `StringToLongConverter` subclass that converts `0` to `""` and otherwise delegates to the original implementation.

If you want `0` to show as empty only when entering new data but show `0` as `0` when editing an existing item, then you can skip `setBean` when initializing the binder and instead create and populate a bean instance only when saving, e.g. something like this:

```
saveButton.addClickListener(event -> {
  Consumer newConsumer = new Consumer();
  binder.writeBean(newConsumer);
  saveInDatabase(newConsumer);
});
```

You can read the documentation at https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder-load.html for more information about the difference between `setBean` and `writeBean`.

Comment: I am already using the convertor class. And after using your the write bean method after submitting the **consumerBinder** is returning null.

Comment: You are using `StringToLongConverter`, I was suggesting that you create your own custom subclass of `StringToLongConverter`. 

You cannot use `getBean()` without `setBean()`. Instead, you can do as I suggested with creating a new bean instance in the submit handler and then using `writeBean` to populate it.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Can you also tell me how to clear the form after submission